# Converting a QuerySet to dictionary without iterating in Python?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to store certain fields from a `QuerySet` object into a python object (e.g. dictionary), but I wonder if it is possible to do this without looping, at least explicitly, in Python?

For example, if the content of the `QuerySet` are as follows:

```py
>> queryset.values_list('parents', 'children', 'x', 'y')
>> [('parent1', 'child1', 1.1, 1.03), ('parent1', 'child2', 1.4, 1.05), ('parent2', 'child1', 0.1, 0.2), ('parent2', 'child2', 1.3, 2.2)]
```

Now, I would like to convert this into a dictionary. The actual structure of the dictionary is of secondary importance, as long as all the information is contained. E.g.:

```py
d = {
  'child1': {
    'parent1' : [1.1, 1.03], 
    'parent2' : [0.1, 0.2], 
  ...
}

# or
d = {
  'parent1': {
    'child1': [1.1, 1.03], 
    'child2': [1.4, 1.05]
  ...
}

# or even: 
d = {
  'child1': [
    # parent1   # parent2
    (1.1, 1.03), (0.1, 0.2)
  ]
  ...
}
```

Of course, I can do this if I loop through the queryset in Python, but is it really necessary to do an explicit `for` loop? Is there a way to populate the dictionary directly from the queryset, similar to how `list(queryset)` gives you a list?

I mostly worry that a for loop will not scale well in terms of performance if I need to retrieve tens of thousands of similar entries. I know that possibly iteration is unavoidable, but at least I'd like to avoid doing that explicitly.

Everything I found online shows how to do this by iterating over the queryset in Python, which is clear to me, but I wonder if there are other, perhaps more performant, ways of doing this.

Comment: What about `values` method? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Comment: I have considered it, but that still returns a queryset object. I need the output to be a python dictionary :/

Answer (score 1):

Use Serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = "__all__"

SomeModelSerializer(instance).data
```

returns

```
{'auto_now_add': '2018-12-20T21:34:29.494827Z',
 'foreign_key': 2,
 'id': 1,
 'many_to_many': [2],
 'normal_value': 1,
 'readonly_value': 2}
```

I think this solution has good performance.`I trust Django REST Framework team :)`

Comment: This is really interesting and something I have not considered at all. Will definitely give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Your Welcome My Friend please do upvote to encourage me helping more people :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, this works on a model instance, not queryset, correct? 

So this is just like doing `vars(instance)`? Maybe I am not using it correctly, but I don't see how this does what I am going for?

Comment: You could pass to it a querset the set the `many` attribute to true

Comment: This is really cool! I think this is quite close to what I am trying to do. One thing about my case is that I also want to get related fields (e.g. `parent__value`). 

Is it possible to include those fields with the above `ModelSerializer`? Currently, it gives me an `ImproperlyConfigured` error saying the field name is not valid for my model.

Comment: @besi You should explain why you need this. I hope someone can give suggestions after you explain "why"

Comment: @besi maybe Serializers will also iterate over QuerySet anyways to convert them into list of dict.